# How do I add an object to an array in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying:

```
await firebase.firestore().doc(`documents/${documentData.id}`).update({
    predictionHistory: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...[predictions])
});
```

where `predictions` is an array of:

```
export interface PredictionHistory {
    predictedAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp;
    predictionText: string;
}
```

But I get an error:

> FirebaseError: Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Shamoon. Did you get anywhere with this? I tried helping with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out and try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating the call, and be looking for:

```
predictionHistory: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(predictions)
```

This will add any elements from the `predictions` array that are not yet in the `predictionHistory` field.